# pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: localhost:27017: [Errno 61]

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, pymongo, flask-login

I'm trying to check for registration, and when it comes to the for loop in the function it stops and gives me the error: pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: localhost:27017: [Errno 61] Connection refused, Timeout: 30s, Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: 631775bf7b8ce9e8bde619fa, topology_type: Unknown, servers: [<ServerDescription ('localhost', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('localhost:27017: [Errno 61] Connection refused')>]>

my app.py :

```
app = Flask(__name__,static_url_path='',static_folder="static")
app.secret_key = 'just a string'
app.config["MONGO_URI"] = "mongodb+srv://Beny1320001:Beny132001@cluster0.dn45iia.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
myclient = pymongo.MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017/')
user_db = myclient["authentication"]
user_table = user_db["user_info"]


@app.route("/register_check", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register_check():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        req = request.form
        req = dict(req)
        query = user_table.find({'uid':req['uid']})
        virable = 0
        for x in query:
            if x['uid'] == req['uid']:
                virable = 1
                break
        req_dict = {'uid':req['uid'],'email':req['email'],'password':req['password']}
        if virable == 0:
            user_table.insert_one(req_dict)
            return render_template('dashboard.html', uid = req['uid'])
        else:
            return render_template('invalid.html', message = 'User alaredy exists')
    return render_template('register.html')
```

Comment: Do you have a mongo server running at `localhost:27017` i.e the same machine where the code is running? The `MONGO_URI` config is not localhost. Should the client be using the other mogo URI instead?

Comment: i dont install anything without the flask and pymongo

Comment: You need to use the correct mongo server URI when creating the client